# start server manually on open-liberty via terminal

Tags: java, open-liberty

I am trying to run an **open-liberty** server on my ubuntu machine. But when I browse to `~/wlp/bin` and type in `./server create name` I recieve the message:

> ./server: 793: ./server: ~/ibm-java-x86_64-80/jre/bin/java: not found

What am I missing? I kept looking around the web for some time now. I tried at least 5 different Java 8 versions but none is working.

Comment: it sounds like the PATH for your terminal is not set up with a valid java installation.  Are you able to successfully run `java -version`?

Comment: yes I am, thats what is so strange.

Comment: how about the output of
uname -m ; file ~/ibm-java-x86_64-80/jre/bin/java; namei -m ~/ibm-java-x86_64-80/jre/bin/java

Comment: **uname -m** -> x86_64 ///  **file ~/ibm-java-x86_64-80/jre/bin/java** ->
/home/max/ibm-java-x86_64-80/jre/bin/java: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=10e11d9dfb7bb7110d301bb640a317f9a53e86eb, not stripped /// **namei -m ~/ibm-java-x86_64-80/jre/bin/java**
f: /home/max/ibm-java-x86_64-80/jre/bin/java
 drwxr-xr-x /
 drwxr-xr-x home
 drwxr-xr-x max
 drwxr-xr-x ibm-java-x86_64-80
 drwxr-xr-x jre
 drwxr-xr-x bin
 -rwxr-xr-x java

Comment: What is the value of PATH, JAVA_HOME, JRE_HOME and WLP_DEFAULT_JAVA_HOME variables in the shell running in your terminal ?
You said java -version works, does ~/ibm-java-x86_64-80/jre/bin/java -version.

Comment: ~/ibm-java-x86_64-80/jre/bin/java -version works, too.  **echo $PATH
~/ibm-java-x86_64-80/jre/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin** //  **echo $JAVA_HOME
~/ibm-java-x86_64-80/jre** // **JRE_HOME and WLP_DEFAULT_JAVA_HOME are empty**

Comment: It's a bit weird that your PATH var has an unexpanded ~ in it, but I can't see how that ultimately leads to that dir being used but not expanded

Comment: How do you set your PATH and JAVA_HOME vars?  As @covener mentioned above, I can't think of how ~ is not expanded unless you did something like this:
export JAVA_HOME=\~/ibm-java-x86_64-80/jre ie, you escaped the tilde and made it a literal.

Comment: even double-quotes would be enough to not expand a ~

Comment: I used: export JAVA_HOME="~/ibm-java-x86_64-80"; export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH           I tried export JAVA_HOME="~/ibm-java-x86_64-80/jre", too.

Comment: Okay it works now. I set the variables now per "nano .bashrc" and I rebooted afterwards. Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it works now. I set the variables now per "nano .bashrc" and I rebooted the VM afterwards. Thanks for your help everyone.